# $\nabla^2$ in spherical coordinate

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $f(r,t)$ is a function of $r$ and $t$ where $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$ and $t$ is just time, then how do we have the following?

$$
\nabla^2 f \stackrel{\text{spherical}}{=} \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\right)
$$

Comment: see the answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2196700/how-can-i-found-nabla-to-prooced-my-schrödinger-equation-study/2196756#2196756

Comment: Just check [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Three_dimensions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments to your question it's said that the laplacian expresed in spherical coordinates is

$$\nabla^2 f=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left[r^2\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\right]+\frac{1}{r^2\sin \theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left[\sin \theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\right]+\frac{1}{r^2\sin^2 \theta}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \phi ^2}$$

You can see that the solution that is given to you has only the first term, so the others have to be zero. It's because the function you are considering depends only on $r$ and not on $\theta$ nor $\phi$, the other coordinates for a point expressed in spherical coordinates: the equation $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ is the definition of the $r$ coordinate knowing the values for $x,y$ and $z$ in cartesian coordinates. We see that $\theta$ and $\phi$ doesn't appear as arguments of $f$ and because this:

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}=0$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\phi}=0$, making zero the second and third terms of the laplacian expressed in spherical coordinates:

$$\nabla^2 f=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left[r^2\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\right]$$

For the function you are studying.